# What is the proper way to use tokens with the Messenger class?

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using version 3.0.3.19 of the MVVM Light Toolkit.

From http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/03/16/whatrsquos-new-in-mvvm-light-v3.aspx:

> Messages can now be sent through the Messenger with a token.
>
> - To send a message with token, use the method overload Send(TMessage    message, object token).
> - To receive a message with token, use the methods Register(object    recipient, object token, Action action) or Register(object recipient, 
>     object token, bool receiveDerivedMessagesToo, Action action)
>
> The token can be a *simple value (int, string, etc…)* or an instance
>   of a class. The message is not delivered to recipients who registered
>   with a different token, or with no token at all.

---

According to the documentation above, I have tried the following in ViewModel A:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("message"), "token");
```

Along with the following in ViewModel B:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, "token", (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg.Notification));
```

---

However, the callback is never executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ViewModelLocator was initializing ViewModel A before ViewModel B. In other words, the message was being sent properly by ViewModel A, but ViewModel B was not yet around to actually receive it.

I changed the order of initialization in the ViewModelLocator and the problem was solved. Also, verified that the Messenger worked with tokens of other types besides String.