# How to call a function(which works with UIElements) in View from ViewModel using MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, view, viewmodel, screenshot, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit and in my View, I have a function that takes a screenshot and returns byte array of that screenshot. Since taking an screenshot (using `UIElement`s) is related to view not ViewModel.

```
byte[] TakeScreenShot(Canvas sourceUiElement)
```

I need to get the return value of the function in my ViewModel but I can't come up with a proper way of doing it.

I other hand if I wanted to do move this function to my ViewModel, I need to have access to that element in view but without referencing the View in my ViewModel (maybe as argument or something to a `Command`?)

Comment: Your suggested edit should be to your question, not the answer.

Comment: I wanted to complete the answer, seems I need to read the faq pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged as MvvmLight, then here is an MvvmLight Toolkit answer. Use said toolkit's `Messenger` class. Simply define the following message classes somewhere in your application:

```
public class TakeScreenshotMessage : MessageBase { }
public class ScreenshotTakenMessage : GenericMessage<byte[]>
{
    public ScreenshotTakenMessage (byte[]content) : base(content) { }
    public ScreenshotTakenMessage (object sender, byte[]content) : base(sender, content) { }
    public ScreenshotTakenMessage (object sender, object target, byte[]content) : base(sender, target, content) { }
}
```

In your code-behind's constructor, register for the TakeScreenshotMessage like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<TakeScreenshotMessage>(this, (msg) =>
{
    byte[] bytes = this.TakeScreenShot(someCanvas);
    Messenger.Default.Send(new ScreenshotTakenMessage(bytes));
});
```

And in your view model, register for the ScreenshotTakenMessage like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ScreenshotTakenMessage>(this, (msg) =>
{
    byte[] bytes = msg.Content.
    //do something with your bytes
});
```

Now you can take a screen shot at any time simply by calling the following from anywhere in your application (i.e. view models, views, helper classes, etc.):

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new TakeScreenshotMessage());
```

Comment: This is much sexier than what we did before!

Comment: @Sabgard - The Send and Register methods are also overloaded to take a Token parameter which can be any object (i.e. I normally just use a constant string).

By using the Token parameter you can register for the same message class in various parts of your application, but limit which listeners actually receive the message. A sort of password if you will.

Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804050/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-tokens-with-the-messenger-class/11830381#11830381) from a question I've asked.

Comment: I'm familiar with Messegers in MVVM Light but it never occurred to me that i could use them in my Views.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the TakeScreenShot with the click event of the button or something in the code behind, have a property on the ViewModel called **Snapshot** for example, and in the click event, you get the byte[] array, assign it to the ViewModel's property **Snapshot**, like so in the code behind.

```
public void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myViewModel = this.DataContext;
    myViewModel.Snapshot = this.TakeScreenShot(someCanvas);
}
```

Depends on how strict you are with MVVM, and some might disagree, I think it is perfectly valid for your view to reference your viewmodel, aka you must know the context you are binding to anyways, but not the other way around.  It is like manually binding to me.

Comment: @Joshscrop I need to call the function from the ViewModel, but in the way you suggest, the function is called from the View, Although if i could find a neat way to notify the View from ViewModel the problem is solved.

Comment: you can always have a hidden checkbox that binds to a property on the viewmodel, say ActivateProperty.  On the view, you can subscribe to the checkedchange event of the checkbox, and do the above code from there.

Comment: yeap, thats what i did but a little bit differently!